# bandwidth throttle on OSX with IPFW for localhost

Tags: mac-osx, bandwidth, localhost, rate-limiting, ipfw

I have my localhost webiste on http://macintosh.local - 127.0.0.1
Testing my website also for IE on the same address in VMWare Fusion
I tried some Apps from hanynet.com/applications/ like WaterRoof.
Never managed to get it working though.

I realize I could do this just with a few command lines in Terminal..
Anyone knows how?

Comment: Too confusing, please state in the text what you want to achieve and what have you done so far?

Comment: I don't really see what's confusing.. I just want the bandwidth throttled on localhost, address 127.0.0.1
I tried with some apps, now I would like to know the command lines.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know why you want to throttle your bandwidth, especially on a localhost connection.  Are you trying to emulate a slow connection?

You can do this with a pipe

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080119112509736